# HTML video no image, just sound

Tags: javascript, css, html, audio, video

All solutions I found didn't take me any further, so I hope you can help me in this issue.

I have embedded an HTML5 video in a simple site. It is working well except in some Safari versions (eg. 8.0), where the sounds plays, but no images are shown.
Sometimes the video shows up after resizing the browser window.

I have 3 full screen divs that get displayed via javascript on scpecific events.

1. First div "introScreen" shows on page load
2. Div "videoScreen" with video shows on click
3. Third div shows after video has finished

I all works except that bug in safari.
Here is the link to the site: [www.whereintimeisnewman.com/temp_index.php](http://www.whereintimeisnewman.com)

Here is the function, that displays and plays the video:

```
function playVideo(){

    document.getElementById("introScreen").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("videoScreen").style.display = "block";

    video.play();
    video.addEventListener('ended',function(){      
        changeToRegistration();
    });
}
```

Maybe it has something to do with the css display settings, but how could I solve that?

Thank you very much for looking into this!

Comment: UPDATE: if controls are enabled in the <video> tag, the video shows. See [Page with controls](http://www.whereintimeisnewman.com) vs. [Page without controls](http://www.whereintimeisnewman.com/temp-index.html). Anyone having a clue?

Comment: Turn up your speakers. Windows: there is a little volume icon in the bottom right of your screen. MacOS: a little icon top right. ;)

Comment: @beingalex: did you read the headline?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

I managed to solve the issue. Apparently Safari has a problem with videos and the "display: none" style attribute.

The parent div "videoScreen" had the css-attribute display:none, which the script turned into display:block when starting the video.

```
document.getElementById("videoScreen").style.display = "block";
video.play();
```

When disabling the line in the css-sheet, the video loaded. Even though the div is now displayed from the beginning, the video and the poster-image only show once the video is being played.

Maybe this solution helps someone else...